Could the Boeing 737 have plausibly existed in the "Fallout" timeline?
Watching the 2024 Fallout TV series, I noticed the settlement of Filly uses a scrapped Boeing 737 cockpit as a prop. This got me wondering: Would the 737, whose first flight was in 1967, have been developed in the diverged timeline of the Fallout games?
Most aircraft present in the Fallout games are based on much older real-life aircraft like the DC-3, T-33, or B-29. However, there’s also much more advanced jets like the Stingray Deluxe or the Jetliner.
The timeline divergence doesn’t have an exact date, so I’m wondering if there’s anything in the lore of the Fallout games that could prove or disprove the existence of Boeing (or the Fallout equivalent) developing the 737.

Not sure why this is attracting close votes unless the idea is that it would be a better fit for the sci-fi stack exchange site. The new fallout tv show is considered canon, lore wise, so it's got the same status as (for example) the StarCraft tie-in novels for lore questions (which are on topic if answerable.)

Voting to reopen. I believe this question is on-topic as per these [meta] discussions: Should lore questions as an entire category be banned? | When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”? | Is “This question requires developer only knowledge” the same thing as developer intent? | Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?

What bugs me about this question is that it answers itself: the series is considered canon, the Boeing 737 (equivalent) exists in the series, hence we can only logically conclude that it has been developed by (ersatz) Boeing in the Fallout universe - whether or not there is evidence for or against it in the earlier games. (Unless it's all just a joke aimed at Boeing's recent technical mishap, but I guess that happened after filming :).

Using the fuselage of a Boeing 737 for the series may have just been a shortcut or oversight by the TV series' props department though - they may have just taken "a broken airplane" without wanting it to specifically be a 737. On the other side of the fence - real-world companies do exist in universe - mostly weapons manufacturers - so it's possible that Boeing exists, despite not appearing in the list of known pre-war companies. I think there's enough nuance to argue either way, and lore questions are on topic, so I'm voting to reopen.

Another somewhat important point: can the word "Boeing" and/or the designation "767" be heard or seen, or is it simply recognizable as a Boeing 767? I don't believe "Lockheed" or "Douglas" are mentioned in the Fallout games, either (but Lockreed is).

The basic premise of Fallout Lore is that the world is extrapolated from the 1940s and 1950s concepts and vision of the future.
In Fallout 4, there is a location called "Skylanes Flight 1981" where a similar cockpit style of aircraft (to a Boeing 737) is found in pieces after crashing. According to the wiki, this aircraft was manufactured by Horizons and is loosely based on the Junckers G. 38 or the Horton Ho 229 jet aircraft.
I suspect that it was easier to get an old airliner cockpit and reuse it for the location than try and make something more canon-safe. I doubt the show makers expected anyone to recognise it directly and draw comparisons.
